# Rate transition block in simulink

Tags: sampling, downsampling

My model is operating at a sampling interval of $\frac{1}{f_0 \times N \times L_{maf}}$  s, (using a fixed point iterative method), now i want the output of my model to be at a sampling rate of $ f_0 \times N $Hz (I am planning to use this downsampled data further in my simulation). I am using the rate transition block and setting the output port sampling time as $ \frac{1}{f_0 \times N} $ s. The output which I get is definitely downsampled, but the magnitude is not the same. How can i make sure that this unwanted magnitude attenuation does not happen. Is there any other way to downsample my initial signal without any loss of magnitude.

Comment: What's the frequency/bandwidth of the signal ? Downsampling should not decrease the amplitude if the signal bandwidth is less than half your new sampling rate.

Comment: The frequency of my input signal is in and around f0 Hz, i have even used the downsampling block in simulink. That block also introduces an magnitude attenuation.